# Paginação de resultado de pesquisa

Tags: php

eu estou com um probleminha em minha paginação de filtro, ela esta paginando corretamente, só não estou conseguindo lincar corretamente o valor do resultado da pesquisa, se alguém puder me ajudar , muito grato.

o código é esse

```
<div id="pagina">

<h1>categoria</h1>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" bordercolor="#666666";>
  <tr style="color:#005789; font-variant:small-caps; font:14px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <td height="30" align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Ilustração</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Operação</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Local/M²</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Comodos</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Data do Anúncio</strong></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="e0e0e0"><strong>Acessar</strong></td>
  </tr>
   <?php
   include"Connections/config.php";

$pg = "$_GET[pag]";
if($pg >= '1'){
 $pg = $pg;
}else{
 $pg = '1';
}

$quantidade = '1'; //RESULTADOS POR PÁGINA
$inicio = ($pg * $quantidade) - $quantidade;


 $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];    


    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $dataVal = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= :dataVal AND imovelNegocio LIKE :tipo AND imovelTipo LIKE :categoria
                AND imovelCidade LIKE :cidade AND imovelBairro LIKE :bairro ORDER BY imovelId DESC LIMIT '.$inicio.','.$quantidade;
    try{
        $query = $conecta->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':dataVal',$dataVal,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':tipo','%'.$tipo.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':categoria','%'.$categoria.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':cidade','%'.$cidade.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':bairro','%'.$bairro.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $totalRegistros = $query->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
        echo $resultado[0][0    ];
        }catch(PDOexception $error_imovels){
          echo 'Erro ao selecionar os imoves!';     
        }
    foreach($resultado as $res){
        $imovelId   =$res['imovelId'];
        $imovelTipo      = $res['imovelTipo'];
        $negocio = $res['imovelNegocio'];
        $imovelCidade    = $res['imovelCidade'];
        $valor   = $res['imovelValor'];
        $thumb   = $res['imovelThumb'];
        $area = $res['imovelArea'];
        $comodos = $res['imovelComodos'];
        $data   = $res['imovelCadastro'];

        echo '<tr>';echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'"><img src="timthumb.php?src=midias/'.$thumb.'&h=90&w=110&zc=1" alt="'.$titulo.'" title="'.$titulo.'" border="0" /></a></td>';
        echo'<td align="center" bgcolor="f0f0f0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'">Operação: '.$negocio.'</a></td>';
        echo' <td align="center" bgcolor="f0f0f0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'">'.$area.'m² em '.$imovelCidade.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'">'.$comodos.' Domitórios</a></td>';
        echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'">'.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data)).'</a></td>';
      echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><a href="index.php?pg=single&imovel='.$imovelId.'" class="veja_mais">Veja Mais</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';

    }
?>

</table>
<!-- inicio botoes -->

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['tipo']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['cidade']) && isset($_POST['bairro'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= '".$dataVal."'  AND imovelNegocio = '".$tipo."'  AND imovelTipo = '".$categoria."' AND imovelCidade = '".$cidade."' AND imovelBairro = '".$bairro."' ORDER BY imovelId DESC ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['tipo']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['cidade'])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= '".$dataVal."'  AND imovelNegocio = '".$tipo."'  AND imovelTipo = '".$categoria."' AND imovelCidade = '".$cidade."'";   

    }
    if(isset($_POST['tipo']) && isset($_POST['categoria'])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= '".$dataVal."'  AND imovelNegocio = '".$tipo."'  AND imovelTipo = '".$categoria."'";    
        }
    if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= '".$dataVal."'  AND imovelNegocio = '".$tipo."'";   

    }
    else{ 
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM up_imoveis WHERE imovelTermino >= '".$dataVal."'";
    }

    try{
        $query_pegaAtivos = $conecta->prepare($sql);
        $query_pegaAtivos->execute();
        echo $totalRegistros = $query_pegaAtivos->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
    if($totalRegistros <=$quantidade){}
else{
 $paginas = ceil($totalRegistros/$quantidade);
 $links = 5;
 if(isset($i)){}
else{$i = '1';}
?>
<div class="paginas">


<?php 

echo "<a href=\"index.php?pg=filtro&amp;tipo=$tipo&amp;categoria=$categoria&amp;cidade=$cidade&amp;bairro=$bairro&amp;pag=1\">Primeira Página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

for ($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
if ($i <= 0){
}else{
echo"<a href=\"index.php?pg=filtro&amp;pag=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";


}
}echo "$pag &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

for($i = $pag +1; $i <= $pag+$links; $i++){
if($i > $paginas){
}else{
echo "<a href=\"index.php?pg=filtro&amp;pag=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
}
echo "<a href=\"index.php?pg=filtro&amp;pag=$paginas\">Última página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
?>
</div><!-- fecha paginas-->
<?php
}
?>
<!--  botoes paginação -->
<h1>Resualtados de sua pesquisa: <strong style="color:#930"> <?php echo $totalRegistros ;?> imóveis encontrados</strong></h1>
</div><!-- fecha pagina-->
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor ? Linkar como assim ?

Comment: o código esta fazendo a paginação,  eu não estou conseguindo manter o resultado da pesquisa no caso seria essa linha "echo "<a href=\"index.php?pg=filtro&amp;pag=$paginas\">Última página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; " tipo ele pagina, mas quando clico na primeira pagina ele pega todo o resultado do banco,

Comment: Então o problema em questão é _paginação com MySQL_ ?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver a questão?